# divide both sides of an equation by Levi Civita symbol

Tags: vector-analysis

$\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial E_{k}}{\partial x_{j}} = - \frac{\partial B_{i}}{\partial t} $

The above is one of the Maxwell's equations - I want to get $\frac{\partial E_{k}}{\partial x_{j}} $ as the subject of the formula

Can I multiply or divide both sides by $\epsilon_{ijk}$ ? is this even allowed when working with suffix notation?

If I multiply both sides by $\epsilon_{ijk}$ I get 3 $k, j$ suffices on LHS which is not allowed - but if I ignore this I get the following

$ \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial E_{k}}{\partial x_{j}} = 6 \frac{\partial E_{k}}{\partial x_{j}}   =  - \epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial B_{i}}{\partial t} $

by dividing by $6$ the above does give me $\frac{\partial E_{k}}{\partial x_{j}} $ as the subject of the formula but the initial equation did have 3 $k,j$ suffices on LHS?

If the above is wrong - is there a way to get $\frac{\partial E_{k}}{\partial x_{j}} $ as the subject of the formula?

Comment: You should take care of the indices : you should not multiply by $\epsilon_{ijk}$. Only one index should be kept and two new ones introduced, I mean that you should take $\epsilon_{mni}$ as the multiplier.

Comment: Just for anyone else who's just found this question, multipling by one $\epsilon$ with two new indices does work, as Jean Marie suggests